# Prevent install two instance of same app on samsung android 13 devices

Tags: flutter, samsung-mobile, android-13

Enabling dual messenger app feature in android 13 with samsung devices, flutter app get installed twice, how to prevent this behaviour?

I don't know what to do

Comment: Same issue I'm facing, any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately not yet.